# php include and htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, include

I have index.php file with:

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="/">home</a></li>
 <li><a href="index.php?id=1">Offer</a></li>
 <li><a href="index.php?id=2">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<?php
   switch ($id) {
    case '1':
       include 'silnik/oferta.php';
       break;
    case '2':
       include 'silnik/kontakt.php';
       break;

    default:
       echo "<p>brak strony</p>";
       break;
  }
?>
```

And i want to change index.php?id=1  to /offer with .htaccess

I have in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1
```

And this doesn't work. Pls help ;)

Comment: There is no mapping from the slug "offer" to the id "1". So you either have to change your switch-statement or add a rewrite-rule for each slug/id-combination. Btw "it doesn't work" adds no information as to what is happening and what you are expecting to happen. With the information you're providing we have to do some guesswork which invariably leads to wrong answers.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do 3 things:

1. change your links: `<a href="/offer"></a>`
2. Make case statements in switch in the desired strings
3. Rewrite:

```
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1
```

Comment: so i change my link to <a href="/offer"></a>, change my chase to case 'offer'and add your code to htaccess and it doesn't work

Comment: Off course you will need `$id` filled with the `$_GET['id']` parameter... but i assumed you already had that :)

Comment: switch($_GET['id']),    case "offer": - ?

Comment: Yes, since `$id` is not automaticly the `id` parameter in the ULR

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1
```

OR

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /index.php?id=$1
```